# Unable to start container in docker compose using a new image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a service in my docker compose file that's based on a different image than my local Dockerfile.  I'm able to start it manually directly with a docker run command but not with docker compose

docker-compose.yml

```
  ...
  omf:
    image: myuser/myapp
    working_dir: /code
    command: python -u myapp.py
    network_mode: host
    ports:
      - "5001:5000"
```

I get this error:

```
omf_1     | python: can't open file 'python': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
grip-server_omf_1 exited with code 2
```

This works:

```
docker run -p 5001:5000 -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash myuser/myapp
```

Comment: That seems like a clear enough error message, and your `docker-compose.yml` fragment is significantly different from your `docker run` command.  I would not be surprised to find a Docker image (especially based on Alpine Linux) that doesn't contain a `python`.  Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: @David Maze, the image is the same in both commands and it has Python.

Comment: Your image has an entrypoint, that you are successfully overriding in your `docker run` command, but your are not overriding the entrypoint in your compose file. You are adding a `command` instead, Docker will pass your command to your entrypoint as an argument. Try double checking your entrypoint and see how to make it work.